# The function onLocationChange(visibleLocation,cfi) does not return cfi for each page( flow="paginated") in @sbrighiu/epubjs-rn

Tags: react-native, bookmarks, epub.js

I am currently using `@sbrighiu/epubjs-rn` in react native for `epub` file reader.
In the documentation the `onLocationChange` function definition is as follow:

> onLocationChange: Function called on every page change, reports current CFI

```
 src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/moby-dick.epub",
```

```
          <Epub 
          flow="paginated"
          ref={(ref) => this.readerRef = ref}
          src={this.state.src}
          flow={this.state.flow}
          location={this.state.location}
          onLocationChange={(visibleLocation, cfi) => {
            this.onLocationChange(visibleLocation, cfi)
          }}
          onLocationsReady={(locations) => {
            console.log("onLocationsReady", locations);
          }}
          onReady={(book) => {
            this.onReady(book)
          }}
          onPress={
            (cfi, position, rendition) => {
              this.toggleBars();
              console.log("onPress", cfi);
              this.setState({
                cuurentLocation: cfi
              })
            }}
          onSelected={(cfiRange, rendition) => {
            rendition.highlight(cfiRange, {});
          }}
          onMarkClicked={(cfiRange, data, rendition) => {
            rendition.unhighlight(cfiRange);
          }}
          origin={this.state.origin}
          onError={(message) => {
            console.log("EPUBJS-Webview", message);
          }}
        />
```

```
  onLocationChange = (visibleLocation, cfi) => {
    console.log("visibleLocation", visibleLocation)
    console.log("cfi", cfi)
    this.setState({ visibleLocation: visibleLocation });
  }
```

The above console returns:
[image]

Unfortunately, as the image above, **onLocationChange** function doesn't return cfi.

only onPress(), onDlbPress(), onLongPress() functions return cfi:
Is there any other option to get the current page's **cfi** ?
OR
**Can you suggest an option to bookmark a specific page ?**

Comment: I believe onLocationChange function returns only one argument, which is the location. You can use the cfi of the end object.

Comment: But end object navigate to end of the chapter

Comment: Any option to bookmark a page?